# react-native-charts customization in line chart

Tags: react-native, linechart

I am using [merryjs/react-native-charts](https://github.com/merryjs/react-native-charts) library in react-native for line-chart. 
The design required is [image: design required]

I have tried to customize but some properties not working or I am not giving them values in a proper manner. My design is :
[image: design made by me]

Properties to customize:

1. remove x axis draw line (in Android this can be done using, `mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false)` but in react native I am unable to do that)
2. Alternate background
3. Remove dot from each point
4. Show dot on drag or click of line

**Code:** [Complete code link](https://gist.github.com/gyanani-harish/b4b73b7ddda44d450eb4cde44735b90d)

```
xAxis: {
          $set: {
            valueFormatter: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q5','Q6','Q7'],
            drawGridLines:false,
          }
        }
 <LineChart
          chartDescription={{ text: '' }}
            style={styles.chart}
            data={this.state.data}
            description={{
            text: ''
          }}
            marker={this.state.marker}
            xAxis={this.state.xAxis}
            yAxis={this.state.axisLeft}

            drawGridBackground={false}
            gridBackgroundColor={processColor('#3AE2CE')}
            borderColor={processColor('teal')}
            borderWidth={10}
            drawBorders={false}
            touchEnabled={true}
            dragEnabled={true}
            scaleEnabled={true}
            scaleXEnabled={true}
            scaleYEnabled={true}
            pinchZoom={true}

            doubleTapToZoomEnabled={true}
            dragDecelerationEnabled={true}
            dragDecelerationFrictionCoef={0.99}
            keepPositionOnRotation={false}
            onSelect={this
            .handleSelect
            .bind(this)}/>
        </View>
```

Comment: able to customize it?

Comment: @christo-pher18 yes, need to change values in node-modules, not all properties exposed properly.

Comment: what all properties? Some briefing would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: line chart with pointer]

If you want a chart like this, consider using [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts).

The code for the above chart is-

```js
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {LineChart} from 'react-native-gifted-charts';

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    {value: 0},
    {value: 50, label: 'S'},
    {value: 148, label: 'M'},
    {value: 80, label: 'T'},
    {value: 145, label: 'W'},
    {value: 90, label: 'T'},
    {value: 130, label: 'F'},
    {value: 70, label: 'S'},
    {value: 145, label: 'S'},
  ];

  const commonStripStyle = {position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: 40};

  const renderBackgroundStrips = () => (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          ...commonStripStyle,
          backgroundColor: '#0A5BA5',
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          ...commonStripStyle,
          top: 40,
          backgroundColor: '#0C4A93',
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          ...commonStripStyle,
          top: 80,
          backgroundColor: '#0A5BA5',
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          ...commonStripStyle,
          height: 60,
          top: 120,
          backgroundColor: '#0C4A93',
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
  return (
    <View>
      {renderBackgroundStrips()}
      <LineChart
        data={data}
        initialSpacing={0}
        spacing={40}
        noOfSections={3}
        height={120}
        curved
        thickness={3}
        hideDataPoints
        hideRules
        color="orange"
        yAxisThickness={0}
        xAxisThickness={0}
        yAxisTextStyle={{color: 'gray'}}
        xAxisLabelTextStyle={{color: 'lightgray'}}
        pointerConfig={{
          pointerStripColor: 'lightgray',
          pointerStripUptoDataPoint: true,
          pointerComponent: () => (
            <View
              style={{
                height: 16,
                width: 16,
                borderRadius: 8,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginLeft: -4,
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  height: 8,
                  width: 8,
                  borderRadius: 4,
                  backgroundColor: 'orange',
                }}
              />
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have rendered the alternate background using a custom component called `renderBackgroundStrips`. This component is rendered in the background (using `{position: 'absolute'}`). The chart is rendered on top of it.